# C# initialization confusion - a stand-alone class of statics

Tags: c#, initialization

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question but I couldn't find anything quite like it searching S.O.    I've inherited a little C# program to enhance and it's mostly a DLL.

I'm expressing the DLL in a sort of pseudo-code to explain my question:
The DLL has 4 classes, 3 "normal" classes and a 4th class of just public static variables that are used as globals by the rest of the DLL

```
  public class CMain
  {
      public CMain ()
      {  
          CFoo Foo = new CFoo(); // CFoo's c'tor is called
          CBar Bar = new CBar(); // CBar's c'tor is called   
          CGlobals.v1 = 123;
      }
  }



   public class CFoo
   {
       ...
   }


   public class CBar
   {
       ...
   }


   public sealed class CGlobals
   {
       public static int v1 = 0;
       public static int v2 = 0;
   }
```

When CMain is instantiated from the DLL's caller, in the debugger the static variables in CGlobals are initialized **first** before anything else happens.  Then CMain's constructor is called.

When I was looking up C# order-of-initialzation I saw where static members of a class are initialized before the class constructor is called, but CGlobals isn't a member of anything; it's just sitting out there, alone, and being referenced from the other classes.

Everything seems to work but it makes me nervous because I don't know the rule it's following.  Can someone please explain what the order-of-initialization rule is that pertains to this, and whether there's anything dangerous about this?

Comment: Are you sure that CGLobals static fields are initialized before calling CMain's constructor? Why should CGlobals be initialized if you did not access it for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that static members are initialized before instance members.  Also, instance field initializers are processed before instance constructors, and static field initializers before static constructors.  Field initializers run in the opposite order along the hierarchy as constructors, i.e., the most derived class's fields will initialized before its base class's fields.

Static initialization occurs the first time a member of a type is accessed.  So, while `CGlobals` may not be initialized at the same time as `CMain`, its members will be initialized the first time you attempt to access one.

There is an exception to this behavior: when running a "release" assembly in .NET 4.0 and later, static field initializers may be deferred at the runtime's discretion.  The initialized values will still be available the first time you try to access them, but they may not all be initialized at once, or in the same order they are declared.  Dependencies should still be honored, though.  If you are dealing with scalar values, and the initializers produce no side effects, none of this should make a difference to you.

Answer (score 1):

yes, static variables are initialized before any constructor is called. the values of those static variables can only depend on other static variables.

Answer (score 1):

The static variables will be initialized before you can call it... but is there any reason why you cannot use a static class?

```
public static class CGlobals
{
    public static int v1=0;
    public static int v2 = 0;
}
```

This is a better representation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: No idea.  I didn't write it.   I just wanted to make sure that C# guarantees that all static variables in an execution unit are initialized first because when I looked up the spec all  could find was where it said that static MEMBERS were initialized first.

Answer (score 1):

Static constructor is called before any access to the class. Any attempt to access to non-initialized class (which has static constructor) will cause calling static constructor.

Access can be:

- Creating instance (object) of the class
- Static member function call
- Access (read or write) to any static property
- Access to any static field